# Github unable to reference CSS sheet from HTML

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I am trying to produce a very basic Webpage using GitHub pages (I'm completely new to github!) and I cannot get the webpage to reference my CSS file when I preview it. There was a post similar to this from two years ago but the answers have not been able to help so I think this is a different issue.

My HTML code is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    type="text/css"
    href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/osmunc/christinaosmun/gh-pages/style.css"/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
     <dir="firstheader">
        <dir="container">
            <h1>Christina Osmunz</h1>
        </dir>
    </dir>
    <dir="container">
        <P> Thank you for visiting my website. I created this website to practice my HTML and CSS coding skills. Please enjoy!
    </dir>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using many different way to reference my CSS file including:

```
//github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>/blob/gh-pages/style.css
//raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repositoryname>/gh-pages/style.css
//github.com/<username>/<repositoryname>/blob/gh-pages/style.css
//rawgit.com/<username>/<repositoryname>/gh-pages/style.css from(https://rawgit.com/)
```

and simply as "style.css"

Both  the files (style.css and index.html) are saved in the same location under a branch called gh-pages in the same project.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If they are saved in the same place (the gh-pages branch root), try just "style.css" without any path info?  Or "./style.css" to reference the current directory.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. The "./"  was all I needed. Not sure why I hadn't thought of it before! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can follow another path for your personal website.

First go to [this page](https://pages.github.com/) and follow instruction for **User website**

Then go to https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages and learn Jekyll.

This is a steep learning curve but not so high. Let's say it will take you two week to

- get it running on your PC for testing,
- master the *liquid* template language,
- try some bootstraps like [jekyll bootstrap](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/) or [Jekyll themes](http://jekyllthemes.org/) or others
- get a really nice site running

And if you need help, ask stackoverflow. Good luck.